# Unable to give rank to the foreach values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, window-functions

I have fetched the values using `wp->get_Results` as follow:

```
global $wpdb;
$select_query = "select * from `eexamhall_result` ORDER BY `quiz_id` DESC, `percentage` DESC";
$select_result = $wpdb->get_results($select_query);
?>
<table class="display table table-bordered table-responsive"><tr><th>Sr No</th><th>Quiz ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Correct Ans</th><th>No Answer</th>
<th>Wrong Ans</th><th>Percentage</th><th>Rank</th></tr>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach($select_result as $select_result){
echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>$select_result->quiz_id</td><td>$select_result->name</td><td>$select_result->correct</td><td>$select_result->zero</td><td>
$select_result->wrong</td><td>$select_result->percentage</td><td></td></tr>";
```

The Data Is showing in form of table as follow

[image]

What I want to do is put the value of rank in 1,2 for quiz id 7 and as the quiz id changes to 6 then I want to start from 1. How can I get this approach

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can compute that information directly in your query, using window function `row_number()`:

```
select er.*, row_number() over(partition by `quiz_id` order by `percentage` desc) rnk 
from `eexamhall_result` er
order by `quiz_id` desc, `percentage` desc
```

Depending on how you want to handle ties (that is, rows that have the same `quiz_id` and `percentage`), you might also want to consider `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.